# Transposing csv files before saving them in the environment in R

Tags: r

I am working with multiple csv files in long format. Each file has a different number of columns but the same number of rows. I was trying to read all files and merged them in one df but I could not do it. 
So far I use this code to read each file individually:

```
try <- read.table('input/SMPS/new_format/COALA_SMPS_20200218.txt', #set the file to read
                  sep = ',',  #separator
                  header = F, # do not read the header
                  skip = 17, # skip 17 firdt lines of information 
                  fill = T) %>% #fill all empty spaces in the df
        t()%>%                  #transpose the data
        data.frame()%>%         #make it a df
        select(1:196)           #select the useful data
```

My plan was to use something similar to this code but I don't know where to include the transpose function to make it work.

```
smps_files_new <- list.files(pattern = '*.txt',path = 'input/SMPS/new_format/')#Change the path where the files are located
myfiles <-do.call("rbind",  ##Apply the bind to the files
        lapply(smps_files_new, ##call the list
               function(x)  ##apply the next function
                 read.csv(paste("input/SMPS/new_format/", x, sep=''),sep = ',',  #separator
                          header = F, # do not read the header
                          skip = 17, # skip 17 first lines of information 
                          stringsAsFactors = F,
                          fill = T))) ##
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same code in `lapply` which you used for individual files :

```
do.call(rbind,  ##Apply the bind to the files
    lapply(smps_files_new, ##call the list
           function(x)  ##apply the next function
             read.csv(paste("input/SMPS/new_format/", x, sep=''),sep = ',',  
                      header = F, # do not read the header
                      skip = 17, # skip 17 first lines of information 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                      fill = TRUE) %>%
                      t()%>%        
                      data.frame()%>%
                      select(1:196)))
```

Another way would be to use `purrr::map_df` or `map_dfr` instead of `lapply` + `do.call(rbind`

```
purrr::map_df(smps_files_new, 
           function(x)  
             read.csv(paste("input/SMPS/new_format/", x, sep=''),sep = ',',  
                      header = F, 
                      skip = 17, 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                      fill = TRUE) %>%
                      t()%>%        
                      data.frame()%>%
                      select(1:196)))
```